# Apple rejected my app as my app doesn't have FB login via Apple SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, registration

I'm building a simple iPhone app with my developer. The main purpose of the app is to simply open my site on its mobile browser. In my site there are two log in options:1. Login via Google and 2. log in via Facebook.

But when my developer went to register this on istore the app has been rejected.
Here is what I received from my developer:
"As per Apple’s guidelines the app should offer features which should provide some interaction with the iOS device like your website offer login using Facebook which should actually be using iOS’s own FB login. Further the website offers searching for contacts, so we can have something like saving those contacts on device memory.

However, all these changes will involve efforts which need planning and are also not small tweak which can be made today and resubmit the app. "

So he is asking me to include log in via FB using APPle SDK otherwise my app can not be submitted.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Apple rejects iOS apps that don't do anything that can't be done by going to your website using Safari. There is no point to your native app. Just send people to your website instead. Either that or update your app so there is an actual benefit to users for having the native app over simply going to the website.

Comment: Agreed.  This app will be and should be rejected.  Go make something more clever!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about 3rd party terms.

Answer (score 8):

Apple's AppStore Review Guidelines include the following:

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as
>   Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be
>   rejected

As I understand it from your description, your app simply shows your website. You should think about some additional features that could be integrated. One that apple seems to have included in your rejection might be a "native login" using the Facebook SDK for iOS.

Comment: +1. This is the sort of thing that clutters up app stores for no good reason.